# Laravel middleware redirect always back to login page even if I successfull logged in

Tags: laravel, redirect, authentication, middleware

I have a big problem with *Laravel middleware*. I used the authentication system from laravel.

I realise that if i just enter a route in my url i come to parts of my page even without login. so started using `middleware`. And if I enter this in my `web.php` file

```
Route::get('/Benutzerverwaltung', 'Benutzerverwaltungcontroller@index')->middleware('auth');
```

it works. if i enter now something in the url it redirects to login page which is correct.

after a successful login with correct user data it redirect to my **HomePage** which is also correct. But now comes the problem if I click on my navigation bar link to another page it redirects back to the login Page even if the User logged in successfully and I don't understand why.

Comment: After a successful login, on your login view do `{{ dd(Auth::user() }}` and then click on the nav links to see if you are still logged in even in the login page. If it doesn't return anything, then you might have been logout (Some session issue). Kindly check and get back.

Comment: @TobivanKenobi can you provide more details

Comment: Hello Saurab I did no this {{ dd(Auth::user() }} in my Startsite right after login but it returns null so that probably means the user is not logged in any more but i dont understand why

Answer (score 0):

**my logincontroller**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    public function logout(Request $request) {
      Auth::logout();
      return redirect('/login');
    }

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/Startsite';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```